# Underscore template issue - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

i'm getting the above error when i try to load one of my underscore templates. I'm guessing its some sort of issue in the for loop (which should probably be an -.each but i don't quite get the structure of those yet).

my template

```
    <script type="text/html" id="Customer-List-View">
    <p> Please click on a customer to select </p>
        <table >
            <thead>
                <th> Customer Name </th><th>Last Invoice date</th><th>Last item added</th>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <% for (var i = 0, i < customers.length, i++){ %>
                    <tr class="cusTableRow"  id="<%=customers[i].objectId %>" >
                        <td> <%= customers[i].custName %> </td>
                        <td> <%= customers[i].custLastInvoiceDate %> </td>
                        <td> <%= customers[i].CustLastItemDate %> </td>
                    </tr>

                <% }; %>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="customerAdd"> Add a new customer </button>

    <p> here should be a set of buttons for working with customers </p>

</script>
```

and its been called by the following

```
$('#tableDiv').html(_.template($("#Customer-List-View").html(), {'customers': globalCustomerList}));
```

I'm sure it something really simple but its my first table in a template and i just can't see the problem.

Any help greatly receieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using commas instead of semicolons in the `for`.

```
<% for (var i = 0, i < customers.length, i++){ %>
```

should be

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++){ %>
```

Comment: or you could use _.each() instead

Comment: i looked at each but wasnt sure about the context setting. I plan to look at it again once i have this page working. thanks for the suggestion though